# how to see what happens inside gym.make('env')

Tags: keras, controls, environment, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

In order to make my own environment and use the some codes of github, I need to see what does happen inside `gym.make('env')` for instance `gym.make('carpole0')`

Where inside the gym github, I am able to find it? I found `https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py` but it does not have make?

How to write the update section of defining an environment (env) for DQN which is not in gym library?
I am looking for an environment definition **"env"** example on github or another resource that is not designed for Atari games. I saw several models but most of them use OpenAI's `gym` library and are written for playing the Atari games which have relatively simple environments. I am looking for a game environment with more complicated states.

I want to write an update function (step function of environment) for the  state `t+1` based on state `t`. What is my problem is that **if the state depends on more than one state before** how do I implement that? I am looking for an example to demonstrate this. It seems to have an obligation to send the time t in environment.

It would be more helpful for me if an example is defined for an **adaptive control** problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store all states of the environment that occur in an array or dictionary.

If your environment needs access to previous states before `t` to determine the next state `t + 1`, those states will be in the array.

```
# array that maintains list of all states the agents experiences
states_experienced = []

# each time a new state is encountered, add it to the array
states_experienced.append(current_state)
```

If order doesn't matter or you'd like to index the states by keys, you can use a dictionary instead.

Comment: Thanks R.F. Have you known any env rather than gym?

Comment: @SaRa OpenAI's [Universe](https://github.com/openai/universe) has a much wider variety of tasks, and is more involved in giving RL networks/algorithms the ability to interact with the real world: playing games, using an actual (virtual) keyboard and mouse to interact with buttons and sliders on webpages, etc. If this helped, please mark my answer as accepted. Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: Thanks R.F! but this is not what I am looking for! I want a step function (update function)